# Dynamic Programming Issue - Fibonacci Sequence

Tags: c, dynamic-programming, fibonacci, unsigned-long-long-int

I was reading [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming#Fibonacci_sequence) Wikipedia article, and attempting to implement a 'map' based solution in C, where a 'map' is just an int array, initialized to 0.

For some reason it works up to `fib(93)`, then starts outputting strange numbers. If it matter's I'm specifying `-std=c99`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// represents a fib num
typedef unsigned long long fib_t;

// the default value of our 'map'
const int FIB_NULL   = 0;

// could get from input, set here for now
const int FIB_MAX    = 100;

// our 'map' for fib nums
static fib_t *fibMap;

// calculate the fib num n
fib_t fib( unsigned int n )
{
    // if this num, n, is not 0 or 1, and is FIB_NULL, then calculate it
    if( n > 1 && FIB_NULL == fibMap[n] )
    {
        fibMap[n] = fib( n-1 ) + fib( n-2 );
    }

    // get it from the map
    return fibMap[n];
}

// used to setup the 'map' for the fibs
static void initFibMap()
{
    // emulate a map
    fibMap = malloc( sizeof(fib_t) * FIB_MAX);

    // initialize it to 'null'
    memset(fibMap, FIB_NULL, sizeof(fib_t) * FIB_MAX);

    // by definition
    fibMap[0] = 0;
    fibMap[1] = 1;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    // setup our 'map'
    initFibMap();

    for( unsigned int i=0; i<FIB_MAX; i++ )
    {
        // breaks on 94
        printf("Fib #%d: %llu\n",i, fib(i));
    }
}
```

Strange output:

```
// . . .
// . . .
// Fib #90: 2880067194370816120  // good
// Fib #91: 4660046610375530309  // good
// Fib #92: 7540113804746346429  // good
// Fib #93: 12200160415121876738 // good
// Fib #94: 1293530146158671551  // WHAT?
// Fib #95: 13493690561280548289
// Fib #96: 14787220707439219840
// Fib #97: 9834167195010216513
// Fib #98: 6174643828739884737
// Fib #99: 16008811023750101250
```

Comment: You *do* realize that you're overflowing even an `unsigned long long right`?

Comment: @Mystical: I had not, I've never worked with numbers this large before. A quick trip to `limit.h #ULONG_MAX` reveals that you're indeed correct. Any recommendations on getting around this issue?

Comment: Unfortunately, C doesn't have native support for bignums. So you'll either need to write your own or use a library such as GMP. If you're willing to sacrifice precision, going to floating-point might be acceptable.

Comment: @Josh you can use some big number support library - for example, GNU bigint.

Comment: @Mysticial: Thank you very much. I don't *need* any precision etc, this was just a learning exercise. But I'll keep that in mind for the future.

Comment: @H2CO3: Thanks, I'll keep that in mind if I ever need to use a large number outside of a learning exercise!

Comment: @Josh see my answer for that. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With such large numbers, you're getting an unsigned integer overflow, which causes a "wrap around" to result in the original result of the operation, modulo `1 << bits`, bits being the bit width of the particular integer type. If you want to represent these numbers, you have to use some kind of bignum library, such as the [GNU GMP.](http://gmplib.org/)

Comment: The behaviour of **unsigned** integers in computations that yield out-of-range results is completely defined by the standard, it's arithmetic modulo `2^WIDTH`.

Answer (score 0):

As number is getting large so integer is getting overflow so "wrap around" is happening
so you can use either GNU GMP library or use string to represent numbers just like i did for factorial of large numbers
link to http://codepad.org/bkWNV0JC